# How can I select rows from a table for specific time ago in php?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I want select all rows from table where added `date< today-15` days in php or sql.

Example:

```
SELECT  * FROM order WHERE date_added< (now()-15days).
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and   [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
$fiftendaysago = date('Ymd',strtotime("-15 days"));
```

And now the query

```
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM order WHERE date_added< '$fiftendayago' ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Build the date in php

```
<?php

$DateString = date('Ymd', strtotime('-15 days'));

$sql = "SELECT  * FROM order WHERE date_added< '$DateString' ";

//Execute your SQL and do your stuff.
```

Comment: Generating time value "-15 days" in php, and comparing against database generated date can be problematic if the DB and Application Hosts are different.

Make sure that both dates refer to same host.

Comment: A fair point but usually not too much of a worry with 15 days!

Answer (score 1):

i usually use a date_diff function

so the sql query will look like

```
SELECT  * FROM order WHERE date_diff(now(), date_added) < 15 ;
```

the function it self

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_diff(date, date)
 RETURNS integer AS
 $BODY$
 select $1-$2; $BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

the database will do the calculation. you can pass the interval of the date using a variable.